# Feeding parameters into a multivar function in Mathematica

Tags: parametric, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to find an intersection point between a plane and a line. I defined my line as a function of $x,y$ and $z$.

`g[x_, y_, z_] := 5 x - 8 y + 2 z - 13`

I named it g because I have the same function defined above (with x and y), and I am unsure whether Mathematica supports polymorphism.

I am trying to feed my parametric equations in for $x, y$ and $z$ in order to get the intersection point using this command.

`g[x, y, z] /. {x -> 7 - 5 t, y -> 2 - 9 t, z -> -6 - 5 t}`

I get this: `-13 - 8 (2 - 9 t) + 2 (-6 - 5 t) + 5 (7 - 5 t)` which is fine I believe, but when trying to solve for $t$ with

`tSol = Solve[g[x, y, z], t]`

I get an error saying: $-13+5 x-8 y+2 z$ is not a quantified system of equations and 
inequalities

Is there a different way to approach this. I know I can do "math by hand" and just plug that into my Show function but I belive my professor want's us to get to that solution and not hardcode.

Thank you

Comment: Try https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Update: I tried assigning it to a variable like this `g[x_, y_, z_] := 5 x - 8 y + 2 z - 13
expr = g[x, y, z] /. {x -> 7 - 5 t, y -> 2 - 9 t, z -> -6 - 5 t} - 
    13 - 8 (2 - 9 t) + 2 (-6 - 5 t) + 5 (7 - 5 t);
sols = Solve[expr == 0, t]` and the kernel says: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

Comment: The error message clearly states that the expression `-13+5x-8y+2z` is not an equation. Simply put, your syntax for `Solve` was wrong. All you needed was to run `Solve[(g[x, y, z] /. ...) == 0, t]`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually disagree that this question should belong on the Mathematica Stack Exchange, because while it is ostensibly about using *Mathematica*, the actual error is, conceptually, a mathematical one; hence it should be answered here.

To this end, observe that your expression for the plane,
$$g(x,y,z) = 5x - 8y + 2z - 13, \tag{1}$$
does not actually define a plane.  It is just an equation that takes a point $(x,y,z)$, and outputs a number.  Mathematically, it is a mapping $g : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$.  I could, for instance, write
$$g(1,1,1) = 5 - 8 + 2 - 13 = -14.$$
It is only until you specify a **level set** of $g$ that you will get a plane.  That is to say, if $g(x,y,z) = c$ for some constant $c$, then the locus of such points $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$ will describe a plane.  One can infer from the expression $(1)$ that such a choice of $c$ is typically $c = 0$; i.e., your plane is actually defined by the condition
$$g(x,y,z) = 5x - 8y + 2z - 13 \color{red}{=} 0. \tag{2}$$
With this in mind, the solution becomes straightforward:  the intersection of $g$ with the parametric line
$$h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3, \\ h(t) = (7-5t, 2-9t,  -6-5t), \tag{3}$$ must satisfy $g(h(t)) = 0$:  i.e.,
$$g(7-5t,2-9t,-6-5t) = -6 + 37t = 0, \tag{4}$$
and the solution readily follows.

The details of implementation in *Mathematica* would be appropriate for the other Stack Exchange site, but suffice it to say, the correct syntax to use would be

```
g[{x_, y_, z_}] := 5x - 8y + 2z - 13
h[t_] := {7 - 5t, 2 - 9t, -6 - 5t}
Solve[g[h[t]] == 0, t]
```